# How can I automate the coloring of the dots(series) in a Scatter Plot?

Tags: vba, excel

http://s3.dosya.tc/server11/yvuh7e/v7m_Quadrant.zip.html

Attached you can find the table that I need help with. In "M Quadrant" sheet I have a graph and a pivot table. There's also a combobox which switches between some names and changes the pivot table therefore the graphic.

What I need is somehow automate the color of the series. When I change to a new name the series remain with their old color, i would like to have the colors via below criterias

```
X axis positive, Y axis positive = Green
X axis positive, Y axis negative = Orange
X axis negative, Y axis positive = Blue
X axis negative, Y axis negative = Red
```

or

this information is also recorded in "M Grafik" sheet, which is the resource of the pivot table, at N Column .  Here are some translations :

```
Yeşil = Green,  Kırmızı = Red, Mavi = Blue, Turuncu = Orange
```

I would like to add the solution below my button and combobox macros. So everytime I change the graphic, colorin should re-run.

Also a screenshot here :

[image]

Best Regards

Comment: Don't vandalize your own question. That's not allowed. By posting it, you have irrevocably licensed its content to stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a method like this to get the X- and Y-Values from the `Series` objects, and then conditionally apply the R/G/B color to each `Point`'s `Fill.ForeColor` and `Fill.BackColor`:

```
Sub foo()

Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim pt As Excel.Point
Dim x, y
Dim s As Long
Dim p As Long

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart '## Modify if needed

'Loop all series in this chart
For s = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(s)
    'Loop all point in this series
    For p = 1 To srs.Points.Count
        'Get the x and y value of this point
        x = srs.XValues(p)
        y = srs.Values(p)
        Set pt = srs.Points(p)
        pt.Select
        'assign color based on x and y value
        '## NOTE: YOU NEED TO SPECIFY THE R/G/B PARAMETERS FOR EACH.
        Select Case True
            Case x >= 0 And y >= 0 'Green
                pt.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                pt.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Case x >= 0 And y < 0 'Orange
                'pt.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(,,)
                'pt.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(,,)
            Case x < 0 And y >= 0 'Blue
                'pt.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0,0,255)
                'pt.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(0,0,255)
            Case x < 0 And y < 0 'Red
                'pt.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255,0,0)
                'pt.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255,0,0)
       End Select

    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Add four columns to your source data for green, orange, blue, red. Use formulas to pull the data from the original data column, according to the conditions you listed above.

Add the four new columns to the scatter chart as new series. Format each series to its respective marker color. Remove the original data series.